# Unicode в консоли C++

Tags: c++, консоль, unicode

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
_setmode(::_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

std::wcout << L"" << std::endl;
_wsystem(L"pause");
return 0;
}
```

Я подключил юникод, но бомба выводятся не корректно как и другие эмодзи. Как это исправить?

Comment: Использовать шрифт, в котором все это есть?...

Comment: @Mikhailo а какой шрифт?

Comment: Ну, в котором есть эти символы... Если, конечно, вы сможете заставить их работать в консоли.

Comment: Под виндой нужно заморочиться. Как минимум сменить кодировку консоли. Вроде так: `std::system("chcp 65001");`

Comment: И почему `L"string"` и `wchar_t`? В `C++20` уже есть `char8_t` и `std::u8string`. Правда, если честно, я не уверен, что вывод их через `std::cout`/`std::clog`/`std::cerr` будет корректно работать, и будет ли работать вообще... Надо пробовать.

Comment: А вообще, я не думаю, что в консоли будут `emoji` выводиться. Это же эмурятор друвнего MS DOS. По сравнению с возможностями Linux - это архачиный кусок г. Если приходится работать под Windows, я обычно использую git bash =)

Comment: Мне представляется, что найти подходящий моноширный шрифт с символами, лежащими за пределами Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane будет крайне затруднительно. Собственно у меня и в браузере  отображается неправильно, через fallback на другой шрифт.